# Selma Mapper Generics Convert BaseMapper<T extends BaseDomain, D extends BaseDTO>

Tags: java, generics, mapper

Currently my system has a basic interface that contains 4 methods for the mapper.

After build an error message appears, someone let me know what it is? I've tried many ways, must have these four generic methods to be converted into certain points of crudservice.

> Error:java: Failed to generate mapping method for type
>   br.com.cron.pdv.domain.Imposto to
>   br.com.cron.pdv.service.service.ImpostoService not supported on
>   br.com.cron.pdv.service.mapper.BaseServiceMapper.asDTO(T) !   --> Add
>   a custom mapper or 'withIgnoreFields' on @Mapper or @Maps to fix this
>   ! If you think this a Bug in Selma please report issue here
>   [https://github.com/xebia-france/selma/issues].

Below the BaseMapper:

```
public interface BaseServiceMapper<T extends BaseDomain, D extends BaseDTO> {

  //Server X Domain
  T asDomain(D source);

  List<T> asDomains(List<D> source);

  D asDTO(T source);

  List<D> asDTOs(List<T> source);

}
```

Interface extends:

```
@Mapper(withIgnoreMissing = IgnoreMissing.ALL, withIoC = IoC.SPRING)
public interface ImpostoMapper extends BaseServiceMapper<Imposto, ImpostoDTO> {

}
```

My Service:

```
public interface ImpostoService extends BaseService<Imposto, Long> {
}
```

My Service:

```
public interface BaseService<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    public T salvar(T t);

    public List<T> salvar(List<T> t);

    public List<T> listarTodos();

    public T buscarPor(ID id);

    List<T> buscarPorDataAtualizacao(LocalDateTime dataInicial, LocalDateTime dataFinal);

    public List<T> listarAtivos();

    public void remover(ID id);

    public void remover(T t);

    public void remover(Iterable<T> iterable);

    public void desativar(T t);

    public void ativar(T t);
}
```

My CrudBaseService:

```
    public abstract class CrudController<T extends BaseDomain, D extends BaseDTO, ID extends Serializable> {


        protected BaseResponse response;
        private BaseService<T, ID> service;
        private BaseServiceMapper<T, D> mapper;


        public CrudController(BaseService<T, ID> service, BaseServiceMapper<T, D> mapper) {
            this.service = service;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public abstract ResponseEntity<List<T>> listarTodos();

        public abstract ResponseEntity<List<T>> listarAtivos();

        public abstract ResponseEntity<T> buscar(@PathVariable(ID) Long id);

        public abstract ResponseEntity<Void> cadastrar(@ModelAttribute T t, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder);

        public abstract ResponseEntity<T> atualizar(@PathVariable(ID) Long id, @ModelAttribute T t);

        public abstract RedirectView remover(@PathVariable(ID) Long id);

        @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_INTEGRACAO_DATA, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> buscarPorDataAtualizacao(@RequestParam(name = DATA_INICIAL, required = false) String dataInicial,
                                                                     @RequestParam(name = DATA_FINAL, required = false) String dataFinal) {

            response = new BaseResponse();

            if (isNullOrEmpty(dataInicial) || isNullOrEmpty(dataFinal)) {
                response.adicionarErro("Existe data(s) vazia(s) ou no formato incorreto");
                return createResponse(response);
            }

            LocalDateTime dtInicial;
            LocalDateTime dtFinal;

            try {
                dtInicial = parseLocaleDateTimeWithoutHour(dataInicial);
                dtFinal = parseLocaleDateTimeWithoutHour(dataFinal);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                response.adicionarErro(ex.getMessage());
                return createResponse(response);
            }

            List<T> result = service.buscarPorDataAtualizacao(dtInicial, dtFinal);

            List<D> resultDTO = null;//mapper.asDTOs(result);
            response.setResult(resultDTO);

            if (resultDTO.isEmpty()) {
                return createResponse(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }

            return createResponse(response);
        }

        ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> createResponse(BaseResponse result) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, result.getSucesso() ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> createResponse(BaseResponse result, HttpStatus status) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, status);
        }
    }
```

My Controller Rest:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ImpostoController.REQUEST_MAPPING_IMPOSTO)
public class ImpostoController extends CrudController<Imposto, ImpostoDTO, Long> {

            public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING_IMPOSTO = "imposto";

            private ImpostoService impostoService;
            private ImpostoMapper mapper;

            @Autowired
            public ImpostoController(ImpostoService service, ImpostoMapper mapper) {
                super(service, mapper);
                this.impostoService = service;
                this.mapper = mapper;
            }

            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<List<Imposto>> listarTodos() {
                List<Imposto> impostoList = impostoService.listarTodos();
                if (impostoList.isEmpty()) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(impostoList, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            @Override
            @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_ATIVOS, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<List<Imposto>> listarAtivos() {
                List<Imposto> impostoList = impostoService.listarAtivos();
                if (impostoList.isEmpty()) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(impostoList, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            @Override
            @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_ID, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<Imposto> buscar(@PathVariable(ID) Long id) {
                Imposto imposto = impostoService.buscarPor(id);
                if (imposto == null) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(imposto, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            @Override
            @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_CADASTRAR, method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public ResponseEntity<Void> cadastrar(@RequestBody Imposto imposto, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
                impostoService.salvar(imposto);
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders.setLocation(uriComponentsBuilder.path(REQUEST_MAPPING_ID).buildAndExpand(imposto.getId()).toUri());
                return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }

            @Override
            @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_ATUALIZAR, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
            public ResponseEntity<Imposto> atualizar(@PathVariable(ID) Long id, @Validated @RequestBody Imposto imposto) {
                Imposto impostoEmBanco = impostoService.buscarPor(id);

                if (impostoEmBanco == null) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                }

                if (imposto.isSituacao()) impostoEmBanco.ativar();
                else impostoEmBanco.desativar();

                try {
                    impostoService.salvar(impostoEmBanco);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(impostoEmBanco, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            @Override
            @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_REMOVER, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
            public RedirectView remover(@PathVariable(ID) Long id) {
                Imposto imposto = impostoService.buscarPor(id);
                impostoService.remover(imposto);
                return new RedirectView(REQUEST_MAPPING_IMPOSTO);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen your question. Selma release 0.15 should solve this issue. Now methods from BaseServiceMapper are read from the ImpostoMapper perspective.